# How to use sub(sub)Categories in Joomla! K2

Tags: php, jquery, joomla, categories, k2

I'm editing a website, and this site uses data-groups, of which I'm **not** familiar (enough) with.

The current result is:
• In K2, I have items in categories, subcategories, and sub-subcategories.
• On the page of the items, there is a horizontal lign, showing each subcategory.
• On that page, I added a dropdown menu under one subcategory. In that dropdown, I have a few sub-subcategories. I would like that when I click on that sub-subcategory, it will show the items from that sub-subcategory.

What do I need to do to make this work?
If I need to post more, feel free to ask, and sorry.

I'll try to explain as good as possible:

**Category.php**

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

?>
<p style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;font-size:120%;padding:1%;background:#007dbe;color:white;margin:1% 0 0.95% 0;">OUTLET</p>
<!--<img src="https://i.ibb.co/3dk77DK/outlet3.png" style="margin: 0 0 1% 0;">-->
            <div class="centered-pills" style="width:98%;margin:0 auto;background:#474747;">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="outlet">
                    <li class="filterTitle">Filter op:</li>
                    <li class="active" id="pointer">All</li>
<li class="active" id="drop-a-down"><a href="#">Example</a>
                     <ul class="drop-a-content">
                       <div class="column-outlet">
                       <ul><strong>Tools</strong>
                         <li class="force-css" data-group="Light"><a href="#">Tool 1</a></li>
                         <li class="force-css" data-group="Light"><a href="#">Tool 2</a></li>
                         <li class="force-css" data-group="Light"><a href="#">Tool 3</a></li>
                       </ul>
                       <ul><strong>Light</strong>
                         <li class="force-css" data-group="Light"><a href="#">Light 1</a></li>
                         <li class="force-css" data-group="Floor"><a href="#">Light 2</a></li>
                         <li class="force-css">Light 3</li>
                         <li class="force-css">Light 4</li>
                       </ul>
                       <ul><strong>Tools</strong>
                         <li class="force-css">Manual tools</li>
                         <li class="force-css">Electric tools</li>
                       </ul>
                       </div>
                       <div class="column-outlet">
                       <ul><strong>Other</strong>
                         <li class="force-css">Other 1</li>
                         <li class="force-css">Other 2</li>
                         <li class="force-css">Other 3</li>
                       </ul>
                       <ul><strong>Roof</strong>
                         <li class="force-css">Roof 1</li>
                         <li class="force-css">Roof 2</li>
                         <li class="force-css">Roof 3</li>
                         <li class="force-css">Roof 4</li>
                      </ul></div>
                     </ul>
                    </li>
<li class="active" id="drop-a-down"><a href="#">Animals</a>
                     <ul class="drop-a-content">
                       <div class="column-outlet">
                       <ul><strong>Blocks</strong>
                         <li class="force-css">Block 1</li>
                         <li class="force-css">Block 2</li>
                         <li class="force-css">Block 3</li>
                       </ul>                       
                    <li class="active" data-group="Category-2"><a href="#">Cats</a></li>
                    <li class="active" data-group="Category-3"><a href="#">Dogs</a></li>
                        <li class="active" data-group="Category-4"><a href="#">Birds</a></li>
                        <li class="active" data-group="Category-5"><a href="#">Elephants</a></li>
                        <li class="active" data-group="Category-6"><a href="#">Tigers</a></li>
                        <li class="active" data-group="Category-7"><a href="#">Lions</a></li>
                        <li class="active" data-group="Category-8"><a href="#">Other</a></li>
        <?php foreach($this->subCategories as $key=>$subCategory): ?>
        <li data-group="<?php echo $subCategory->name; ?>"><a href="#"><?php echo $subCategory->name; ?></a></li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
            </div>
    <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:2%;">
      Get your products now!
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

<div class="inner">
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:-5%;">
        <?php if($this->params->get('subCategories') && isset($this->subCategories) && count($this->subCategories)): ?>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="centered-pills" style="width:98%;margin:0 auto;">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li class="filterTitle">Filter:</li>
                    <li class="active" data-group="All"><a href="#">Alle</a></li>
                    <?php foreach($this->subCategories as $key=>$subCategory): ?>
                    <li data-group="<?php echo $subCategory->name; ?>"><a href="#"><?php echo $subCategory->name; ?></a></li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

            <?php else: ?>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
            <p class="text-center" style="display:none;">Promotions in: <span class="divider"></span><strong><?php echo $this->category->name; ?></strong> <span class="divider"></span><a href="acties">Show all products</a></p>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if(isset($this->leading) && count($this->leading)): ?>
        <ul id="grid">
        <?php foreach($this->leading as $key=>$item): ?>
            <?php $this->item=$item; echo $this->loadTemplate('item'); ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
      <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:2%;font-style:italic;font-size:75%;">
      All products are property of us.
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php if($this->params->get('catDescription')): ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="disclaimer">
                <?php echo $this->category->description; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
  /* initialize shuffle plugin */
  var $grid = jQuery('#grid');
  $grid.shuffle({
    group: 'all',
    itemSelector: '.portfolio-item', // the selector for the items in the grid
    speed: 500 // Transition/animation speed (milliseconds)
  });
  /* reshuffle when user clicks a filter item */
  jQuery('.nav-pills li').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // set active class
    jQuery('.nav-pills li').removeClass('active');
    jQuery(this).addClass('active');
    // get group name from clicked item
    var groupName = jQuery(this).attr('data-group');
    // reshuffle grid
    $grid.shuffle('shuffle', groupName );
  });
});
```

Comment: Someone call 1-555-saveme! =)

Comment: Are you aware that there is a dedicated Q&A site exclusively for Joomla support? It is [joomla.se] and it is one of the menu items in your Joomla site's backend/administrator Help menu.  Perhaps post your Joomla questions there to speak to an audience that has a more intimate understanding of Joomla.

Comment: I did not know that, thanks a lot! :)